# Icon in menuitem odoo 8

Tags: icons, menuitem, odoo-8

There is an attribute 'icon' in menuitem with value='STOCK_HOME', but this value doesn't store in ir_ui_menu table. An default value 'STOCK_OPEN' has set in ir.ui.menu model, it saves automatically. How can i save custom specified value for field 'icon'

I tried this:

```
<menuitem name="Category" id="menu_category" parent="menu_maintenance_config" icon="STOCK_HOME' />
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like **web_icon="account,static/description/icon.png"**:

```
<menuitem name="Invoicing"
    id="menu_finance"
    groups="group_account_user,group_account_manager,group_account_invoice"
    icon="fa-usd"
    web_icon="account,static/description/icon.png"
    sequence="40"/>
```

OR

```
<menuitem name="Employees"
    id="menu_hr_root"
    groups="base.group_hr_manager,base.group_hr_user,base.group_user"
    icon="fa-user"
    web_icon="hr,static/description/icon.png"
    sequence="75"/>
```

[Refer this link for more info](http://openerp-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03_module_dev_04.html)

Comment: Thanks sharma. I tried that but nothing happened. In your example the value "fa-usd/fa-user" doesn't save in ir_ui menu table by code. it will through UI, settingd -> Technical - >User Interface -> Menu Item  and select on menu and select an icon name from icon selection field. then it will save in table. I am trying to do it by  code?